# Partition the integers

Tags: elementary-set-theory, examples-counterexamples, set-partition

I know I can divide the integers into 2 different infinite sets such that they form a partition of the integers, like the odd numbers, and the even numbers.

Is there another (trivial) way to partition the integers into $3,4$ or more **different** infinite sets?

Comment: natural number? or integer?  group is a special term in mathematics.

Comment: Integers. sorry.

Comment: I think you don't mean group right? are you looking for something like partition? A group need an identity element.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to create partitions of the integers using infinite subsets. If you want to partition the integers into $3$ sets, you can consider the reminder of the integer when divided by $3$ (for more information look at modulo $3$ integers). However, there is nothing special about $3$, therefore you could look at the reminder modulo $n$ for any natural number you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want n partitions, just partition them by divisibly by n, so i-partition includes all the integers n_i such that n_i mod n = i.

Another way to divide in 2 partitions is to look at all the numbers that are greater or less than equal to say 0